# Bootstrap clickable and sortable - can not click after sorting

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-sortable, bootstrap-table, clickable

I'm using Bootstrap 4.2.1 with bootstrap-table 1.13.3 to create a table that is sortable and clickable per row.  Each row is clickable until the table is sorted.

After sorting Google tools shows the TR click event handler has been removed.

The click handler is added in the onload event handler as per below.  What should I do to ether prevent the click event being removed or restore the click event after the sort operation?

```js
function onLoaded(){
   $(function(){
      $('.table tr[data-href]').each(function(){
         $(this).click(function(){
         document.location = $(this).attr('data-href');
        });
      })
    });
}
```

```css
tr.clickable-row {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.13.3/bootstrap-table.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.13.3/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body onload="onLoaded()">
  <wrapper class="d-flex flex-column">
      <main class="container">
          <div class="table-responsive-sm">
              <table data-toggle="table" data-sortable="true" class="table table-sm table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                  <thead class="thead-light">
                      <tr>
                          <th data-sortable="true" scope="col">
                              For
                          </th>
                          <th data-sortable="true" scope="col">
                              Name
                          </th>
                      </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                      <tr class="clickable-row" data-href="ZZZZ.html?YYYY=32">
                          <td>Paul Read</td>
                          <td>23/05/2018 13:11</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="clickable-row" data-href="ZZZZ.html?YYYY=31">
                          <td>Paul Read</td>
                          <td>23/05/2018 13:09</td>
                      </tr>
                  </tbody>
              </table>
          </div>
      </main>
  </wrapper>
</body>
```

Many thanks
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have edited your code into this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eitanmg/frmLy3q8/12/

The key is to use the built-in `onClickRow` event, so the functionality still remain after sorting / searching / filtering the table.

other edits that were made:

I have deleted the `onload="onLoaded()"` in body tag and remove the `onLoaded()` function completely. I have added `id="table"` to table tag, so it could be referenced from the javascript code. and instead of the `onLoaded()` function i used the `onClickRow` event as:

```
$('#table').on('click-row.bs.table', function (row, $element, field) {
    alert("you are about to navigate to the following url: " + $element._data.href)
    document.location = $element._data.href;
});
```

Comment: thank you - really useful, I am as you may have guessed new to this js, bootstrap, jQuery etc Cheers!